# Relation does not exist when trying to access existing DB

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I've setup the connection to the database in Wildfly without any problems and the connection works.

I'm creating a Twitter clone but when I try to access the DB I get an error saying the following:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "tweet"
>   does not exist

JPA doesn't seem to automatically create the schema. Running similar code in another project automatically created the entity schemas. I'm very lost as to what is going on here.

I have a basic Tweet entity

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Tweet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String tweet;
    private String user;

    public Tweet() {}

    public Tweet(String tweet, String user) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTweet() {
        return tweet;
    }

    public void setTweet(String tweet) {
        this.tweet = tweet;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And the DAO uses the following code to access the data:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class TweetDaoImpl implements TweetDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Tweet insertTweet(Tweet tweet) {
        em.persist(tweet);

        return tweet;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Tweet> getUserTweets(String user) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT tweet FROM Tweet tweet WHERE tweet.user = :user");
        query.setParameter("user", user);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Tweet> getAllTweets() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT tweet FROM Tweet tweet");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Tweet updateTweet(int id, Tweet tweet) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Tweet deleteTweet(int id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: JPA doesn't even create the schema automatically though. Which is strange. So it basically doesn't exist. I ran similar code in another project (there being employees instead of tweets) and upon deploying it, JPA automatically created the entity schema. I have no idea what is going on at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the entity was using a field named "user". Changing the field name to something else made everything work.

User is a reserved word in Postgresql.